# Parsing of two different message types coming in same message channel

Tags: java, parsing, message, objectmapper

We are going to receive the two types of messages from same MQ queue. The structure of these two messages is completely different, there is no common field. I have corresponding POJO's for both the classes. How to I identify smartly which message corresponds to which POJO?

What I am currently doing is as follows:

```
receivedMessageClassA = objectMapper.readValue(payload, ClassA.class);
```

Check if the parsing above succeeds OR check if one of mandatory field is present in receivedMessageClassA.

If the above check fails, do the parsing for second class

```
receivedMessageClassB = objectMapper.readValue(payload, ClassB.class);
```

However this approach is error prone and I am not completely satisfied with it. Can someone help here please?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe the best method is to use `instanceof`:

```
if (payload instanceof ClassA)
   receivedMessageClassA = objectMapper.readValue(payload, ClassA.class);
else
   receivedMessageClassB = objectMapper.readValue(payload, ClassB.class);
```